# My app.js file won't load on local website

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome

When using VSC to open the site I am working on in my browser (chrome), the index.html and styles.css files load but the app.js does not. I get the following errors

[image]

I tried commenting out various lines in my app.js file but could not pinpoint the problem.
My app.js file.
`

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.question-btn');

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const question = e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
        question.classList.toggle("show-text");
    });
});
```

I revisited the problem this morning and now the site works as it should. Here is the html anyway. I will still like to know how to solve this issue in the future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Q & A</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- extra fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="questions">
        <!-- title -->
        <div class="title">
            <h2>General Questions</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- questions -->
        <div class="section-center">
            <!-- single question -->
            <article class="question">
                <!-- question title -->
                <div class="question-title">
                  <p>do you accept all major credit cards?</p>
                  <button type="button" class="question-btn">
                      <span class="plus-icon">
                          <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class="minus-icon">
                        <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <!-- question text -->
                <div class="question-text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quasi aliquid quibusdam dicta nam voluptatum totam, ipsam ab maxime sint.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <!-- end single question -->
            <!-- single question -->
            <article class="question">
                <!-- question title -->
                <div class="question-title">
                  <p>do you support local farmers?</p>
                  <button type="button" class="question-btn">
                      <span class="plus-icon">
                          <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class="minus-icon">
                        <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <!-- question text -->
                <div class="question-text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quasi aliquid quibusdam dicta nam voluptatum totam, ipsam ab maxime sint.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <!-- end single question -->
        <!-- single question -->
            <article class="question">
                <!-- question title -->
                <div class="question-title">
                  <p>do you use organic ingredients?</p>
                  <button type="button" class="question-btn">
                      <span class="plus-icon">
                          <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class="minus-icon">
                        <i class="far fa-minus-square"></i>
                      </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <!-- question text -->
                <div class="question-text">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto quasi aliquid quibusdam dicta nam voluptatum totam, ipsam ab maxime sint.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
    <!-- end single question -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share how you are calling `<script>` in your index.html?

Comment: added to the original post